# Trying to show every rows in a database table but is only showing the first

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have in my database a table "Categories" where I have this:  [image]

And now with php Im showing the categories without "father", in other words the categories when the id_father is null. Like Warnings and Tecnology.

I´m doing like this:

```
<div class="block cat" style="display:block">
        <div class="title">Categories:</div>   
         <?php
            $readCat = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories where id_father IS null");  
            $readCat->execute();
            $num_rows_readCat = $readCat->rowCount();
            $readCategoriesResult = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(!$num_rows_readCat >= 1)
            {
                echo 'There is no categories registers yet.';
            }
            else
            {       
         ?>                            
        <table width="560">
          <tr class="cts">
            <td>category Name:</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>tags:</td>
            <td>Date:</td>
          </tr>
          <?php
                    foreach($readCategoriesResult as $cat)
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$cat['name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cat['content'].'</td>';
            echo '<td align="center"><img src="ico/ok.png" alt="3 Tags" title="3 Tags" /></td>';
            echo '<td align="center">'.date('d/m/Y H:i',strtotime($cat['date'])).'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
```

And its working fine, I already have a my first category "Warnings" showing.

But I only have the first category and I want to show every category that I have in my database, in this case I also have Technology but its only showing the Warnings category.

I alraedy tried with a foreach loop but its not working...

Somebody there is seeing where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ($row = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['content'].'</td>';
        echo '<td align="center"><img src="ico/ok.png" alt="3 Tags" title="3 Tags" /></td>';
        echo '<td align="center">'.date('d/m/Y H:i',strtotime($row['date'])).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
}
```

The while loop means all rows will returned will be echoed out.

Comment: Thank you, so in that cause I dont need my $readCategoriesResult = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); right?

Comment: No not as you are using it. what you are basically doing there is adding the results array to a variable - this is useful in some circumstances but not for what you are doing at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

`$readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` will only fetch one result. You need to either:

1. Use `$readCat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and use a foreach loop, as mentioned.
2. Use `$readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` in a while loop.

Here's the while loop:

```
while ($result = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //Echo HTML here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all the records, you will need to do a `fetchAll` then loop over the records:

```
$readCategoriesResult = $readCat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

...

foreach($readCategoriesResult as $cat){
    //display the table row
}
```

Alternatively, you could `fetch` in a while loop, but I like `fetchAll`

Answer (score 1):

> Somebody there is seeing where is the problem?

The problem is lack of foreach loop and may be some confusion between fetch methods. you can read on them in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: the above answer gave you a while loop, you can use that aswell